# XSLT XML Sort - Missing Root Attributes

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml document i need to sort. I have this working..
However the root element after the sort is missing attributes 
I tried [MS Forum post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/32236315-6cd7-48c6-a9e0-fd0520af5056/xslt-transform-question-how-to-preserve-the-root-elements-attributes-during-transform?forum=xmlandnetfx) that did not work. I want my root node attributes. Thanks

Input XML then XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TestProduct ProductName="SCADA" MaxResults="20" SamplesUsed="5">
  <TestCollection TestName="TestABC" Expected="Passed" Status="STABLE">
    <TestInfo TestResult="Passed" Version="8.0.1.19" Time="" Duration="" />
    <TestInfo TestResult="Passed" Version="8.0.1.18" Time="" Duration="" />
  </TestCollection>
  <!-- Lots of TestCollection's -->
  </TestProduct>
```

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="TestProduct">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="TestCollection">
                <xsl:sort select="@TestName" order="ascending"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing copying attributes of `TestProduct` element. 
Adding `<xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>` as the first child of `<xsl:copy>` will do.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="TestProduct">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="TestCollection">
                <xsl:sort select="@TestName" order="ascending"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Below XSLT has an Identity Transform Template that copies the nodes as they are. This is the way I prefer:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="TestProduct">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="TestCollection">
                <xsl:sort select="@TestName" order="ascending"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Identity transform template -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, it works !! Any way to stop this affect "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><TestProduct ProductName="SCADA" MaxResults="20" SamplesUsed="5"><TestCollection" where the output does not have the newlines between elements ? NB: Using C# to run XSLT so Settings possible ?

Comment: I think you mean to indent the output XML. Please see my edit to add `<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>`